# How to properly use fieldsets in vespa?

Tags: vespa

I'm seeing a warnings like these when running vespa-deploy prepare command

`The matching settings for the fields in fieldset 'default' are inconsistent (explicitly or because of field type). This may lead to recall and ranking issues.`

`The normalization settings for the fields in fieldset 'default' are inconsistent (explicitly or because of field type). This may lead to recall and ranking issues`

`The stemming settings for the fields in the fieldset 'default' are inconsistent (explicitly or because of field type). This may lead to recall and ranking issues.`

After going through some documentation, I'm almost sure that this is something related to fieldsets. What is causing these warnings? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this if your fields referenced in the fieldset has different settings in any of the matching,stemming or normalization (explicit or implicit given by the field type). Query is only processed using one set of configuration while on the document side during indexing each field is processed with it's own settings hence having different settings might lead to recall issues.

Comment: So, I assume the problem is that there is a property named "category", which is an attribute and fieldset contains fields which are not attributes. Interestingly, I have not configured anything for matching, stemming or normalization (Except attribute:fast-search).

Comment: Yes, if you combine string field attribute which defaults to match:word (exact style matching) and a indexed string field which defaults to match:text you will get this warning.

Comment: Unrelated but would appreciate if you could resolve the other vespa related questions if you are happy with the answers.